# Efficieny of stl vector and queue

Tags: c++, vector, stl, queue

I want to implement a program using either `vector` or `queue` data structure. The function requires frequently pushing and popping some elements (e.g. 8 elements) from the data structure to process these elements, and finally the data structure will be empty. The processing order doesn't matter so both `vector` and `queue` are ok. I want to know which one has higher efficiency if I need to frequently push and pop from it. Thank you.

Comment: Is there some reason not to use `stack`?

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. A `std::queue` is a container wrapper. If you want the wrapped container to be a `vector`, you can have that, at which point performance is identical. Better would be comparing `std::vector` to `std::deque`, the default container for `std::queue`.

Comment: *"The processing order doesn't matter so both `vector` and `queue` are ok."* -- this sentence would make more sense if you replace `vector` by `stack`. That would clearly mean that it doesn't matter if the push/pop is LIFO or FIFO.

Answer (score 2):

`std::queue` isn't a container. It is a container adapter. By default, it adapts `std::deque`.

> The function requires frequently pushing and popping some elements ... The processing order doesn't matter

This seems to imply that you can pop from the same end where you push (LIFO). In that case, another container adaptor would be appropriate: `std::stack`. It also adapts `std::deque` by default. There is no difference in efficiency of `std::vector` and the efficiency of `std::stack` that adapts `std::vector`. There can be a difference in using `std::deque` depending on the details of how you use it.

Comment: I believe that by default `std::stack` adapts `std::deque`

Comment: @jkb Oh, so it does. I didn't check. Fixed.